# Text Change Listener for EditText in custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

In my android app I have listview with `EditTexts`. After changing `EditText` value I'm storing new value in `ArrayList` in `afterTextChanged`. But something working wrong cause after editing only one field, `ArrayList` getting several items with same edited string. How I can make `ArrayList` to get edited string for every field only once?

```
class MyListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<KeyValueList>
{
private int layoutResource;

MyListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<KeyValueList> keyValueList)
{
    super(context, layoutResource, keyValueList);
    this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
    }

    final KeyValueList keyValuelist = getItem(position);

    if (keyValuelist != null)
    {
        TextView key = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.key);
        EditText value = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.value);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

        value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> edit = new HashMap<>();

                edit.put("string", s.toString());

                openEntry.edit_list.add(edit);
            }
        });
....
}
```

Comment: You need to use potion,add your new value in your `List` on that potion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would use *set*TextChangedListener if it exists, or remove all TextChangedListeners from a view before you add your new one, it will probably work.

These views are recycled, but you're adding new listeners to them all the time. I think that might be the problem.

Comment: There is no setTextChangedListener. But how i can remove all TextChangedListeners?

Comment: If you move new TextWatcher() to a variable if that is possible, so you only create it once and re-use it, you can remove it from the view and add it to the view, where you right now just add it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did like You said and It started working better, but still there is a problem. If for example I have "hello" in my `edittext` and I'm adding "aaa" to it, `arraylist` getting "helloa", "helloaa", "helloaaa". Maybe You can help me with this too?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar issue,solved by  making `EditText` as `final`and checking condition `hasFocus()` ie

```
final EditText value = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.value);
...
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{

   if(value.hasFocus()){
        HashMap<String, String> edit = new HashMap<>();
        edit.put("string", s.toString());
        openEntry.edit_list.add(edit);
   }

}
```

this may help some one with same problem